# is there a way in Visual Studio 2013 to automatically clean a project before building it?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, msbuild, solution

I was thinking to add some code in the .csproj file in the following tag, that would automatically clean the solution before a build attempt:

```
  </ProjectExtensions>
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
      // Clean the project <------
</Target>
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
</Target>
</Project>
```

any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Use Rebuild Solution rather than Build Solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force msbuild to clean or rebuild](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494248/how-to-force-msbuild-to-clean-or-rebuild)

Comment: @Ryios Thanks a lot, the link to that question helped me a lot!

Comment: Also see this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334774/how-do-i-force-a-rebuild-when-the-project-configuration-changes